# Sampling from a pareto distribution in R - getting values below scale parameter

Tags: r

I am sampling from a Pareto distribution using rpareto from package actuar.

What I find strange is that I keep getting values below the defined scale parameter. I was under the impression they should all be above it.

```
tail <- rpareto(2,scale=y_0,shape=a_hat)
```

and I get in my vector values below y_0. Does anyone have an explanation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the formulation used by the function in the `?rpareto` help page. Perhaps they parameterized the distribution differently than you do. From the help page:

[image]

So they say that the returned values with be `>0`. The support does not depend on the parameters.

If you are comparing this to the [version on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) they are basically doing a translation of

```
y = x - scale
```

Comment: yes, that's precisely it! I don't know why I didn't notice this difference... thanks!